# Docker Remote API Build with Node and Dockerode

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm attempting to use the Docker Remote API to POST /build.

My Dockerfile looks like.

```
FROM node:5.8.0

COPY . /my-project

WORKDIR /my-project

RUN npm install

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I have this exact file in a .tar since that is what the API requires.  The problem is it executes the commands - except when it gets to npm install - it says package.json is not found.  In fact the only thing in the /my-project directory is the Dockerfile.  It seems it does not understand how to copy over the actual directory.

I am using dockerode node module.

```
var Docker = require('dockerode');
var docker = new Docker();

docker.buildImage('Dockerfile.tar', {t: 'myproject'}, function(err, stream) {
  if(err) return;

  stream.pipe(process.stdout, {end: true});

  stream.on('end', function() {
    done();
  });
});
```

When I run via the command from my terminal inside the directory like so

```
docker build .
```

It builds perfectly fine and then I can run and access my container locally.

Comment: what's the path of .tar file  ? you want to copy this file (.tar file) to /my-project folder, right ?

Comment: The tar file is local to the directory in which it is excuted.  It does find the Dockerfile.tar

I execute with node test.js  and the tar file is on the same level as test.js

Answer (score 0):

human error.

the contents of /my-project needed to be in the tar as well.  that way when 
`COPY . /my-project` is executed it copies the contents in the .tar into the dir.